# Goofys mount AWS S3 bucket inside container not reloading

Tags: amazon-s3, mount, goofys

I am using [goofys](https://github.com/kahing/goofys) to mount the AWS S3 bucket. I set up the mount inside the container image. Everything was working fine but recently I have noticed that the content is not properly reloading.
For example, I have a directory A with a .txt file. I noticed that the timestamp got updated but the content inside doesn't.
However, when I tried to create a new directory and a new text file in the bucket. It shows up in the local mount inside the container.
I suspect that it only happens for existing directories and files. Also, it might only happen when the bucket is getting large in size.
I use goofys with `allow_other` option and do not specify any cache option at all. Does anyone know how to fix this?